# How to output debugging information from intern functional tests?

Tags: intern

When I run a unit test using intern, it writes console.log to the standard output, which is useful when developing the tests.

However, functional tests apparently suppress output - writing to console.log does not do anything, and I can not find any way to output text to the console. Which means when something goes wrong, it is very difficult to find out why.

Answer (score 2):

Where `console.log` outputs text depends on what environment the tests are running in. When you run `intern-client`, which only runs unit tests, the test code always runs in the Node.js environment and `console.log` writes to stdout in the terminal.

When you run `intern-runner`, unit tests run in the browser while functional tests run in Node.js. This means that `console.log` statements in the *unit* tests (those specified in the `suites` property of the intern config) will not print to stdout in the terminal, but instead will be output in the browser's console. Log statements in *functional* tests (those specified in `functionalSuites`) will be output to the terminal's stdout. The exception is log statements in `execute` or `executeAsync` blocks, which will be output to the browser's console since code in those blocks will actually be executed in the browser.